# Generate a more readable antlr parser

Tags: antlr

Is there are an option to generate a more readable antlr parser. Say, to disable Token->DFA optimization?

Comment: Are you trying to build the skeleton of a parser with the intention of hand-maintaining it in the future? Would writing a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent) by hand from the start be a better option?

Comment: One motivation is debuggability, another one is simplicity:  
Instead of having this code to match the first occurence of 'once'

// Exp.g:66:2: ( 'once' condition ( 'then' )? action )
            int alt13=4;
            alt13 = dfa13.predict(input);
            switch (alt13) {
                case 1 :
                    // Exp.g:66:4: 'once' condition ( 'then' )? action
                    {
                    match(input,64,FOLLOW_64_in_once193); if (state.failed) return ;
                    pushFollow(FOLLOW_condition_in_once195);

Antlr could just generate the following:

Comment: if(!input.startsWith("once"))return;

Comment: Instead of writing a recursive descent parser completely by hand, a disableDfaOptimization flag in Antlr could make the task much easier.